# plot middle of candle between open high and open and low in pine-script 4

Tags: pine-script

i am trying to plot the difference between low_mark and open and high_mark and open and the current code is placing the line above instead of in between.

```
//@version=4
study("My Final Version", overlay=true, max_bars_back=500)
 
maxBarsBack = 500
 
previousRange = open[1] - close[1]
 
line bullEngulfOpen = na
line bullEngulfLow = na
line bullEngulfMid = na
 
line bearEngulfOpen = na
line bearEngulfHigh = na
line bearEngulfMid = na 
 
isBullEngulf = previousRange > 0 and close > open[1]
isBearEngulf = previousRange < 0 and close < open[1]
```

...i want to plot the mid_mark(yellow line) between the low_mark(red line) and the high_mark(green line).  its placing the line above because i think it's looking at the wrong candle.
[image]

```
low_mark = nz(min(low, low[1]), low)
high_mark = nz(max(high, high[1]), high)
mid_mark= (nz(min(low, low[1]), low) + nz(max(high, high[1]), high)) /2
X_ = bar_index -1
 
if isBullEngulf
    bullEngulfOpen := line.new(X_, open[1], bar_index, open[1], extend=extend.right, color=color.green) 
    bullEngulfLow := line.new(X_, low_mark, bar_index, low_mark, extend=extend.right, color=color.red) 
    bullEngulfMid := line.new(X_, mid_mark, bar_index, mid_mark, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow) 
    buy_message_1 = "Buy 1(Open) = " + tostring(open[1]) + "  Buy 2(Mid) = " + tostring(mid_mark) + "  Buy 3(Low) = " + tostring(low_mark) 
    alert(message=buy_message_1)
 
 
if isBearEngulf
    bearEngulfOpen := line.new(X_, open[1], bar_index, open[1], extend=extend.right, color=color.green)   
    bearEngulfHigh := line.new(X_, high_mark, bar_index, high_mark, extend=extend.right, color=color.red)
    bearEngulfMid := line.new(X_, mid_mark, bar_index, mid_mark, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow) 
    //sell_message_1 = "Sell Price 1 (Open)  = " + tostring(open[1]) + "   Sell Price 2 (High) " + tostring(high_mark)
    sell_message_1 = "Sell 1(Open)  = " + tostring(open[1]) + "   Sell 2(Mid) " + tostring(mid_mark) + "   Sell 3(High) " + tostring(high_mark)
    //alert(message= sell_message_1)
// ALERTS
```

Comment: Your green lines aren't high_mark though, they're the open[1] value

Comment: yeah sorry, so i would need the plot between the open and low and between the open and the high.

Comment: Then you need to add a variable and calculation for it, mid_mark is between the high and low values not between open[1] and high/low

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work                                                                           
mid_markL= (nz(min(open, open[1]), open) + nz(max(low, low[1]), low)) /2
mid_markH= (nz(min(open, open[1]), open) + nz(max(high, high[1]), high)) /2

Comment: mid_markL = (open[1] + low_mark) / 2

Comment: thanks, its still looking at the wrong candle.. its plotting it on the right and not on the candle that has the green and red line....

Comment: nevermind it worked.. thank you for your help!  i really appreciate it!